# How to access direct address of raw folder?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a music album app but I should copy the songs to SDcard that duplicate the size of app and it's not proper for low memory space devices. I want to access direct address of raw folder itself (not the files in it). Is there a better way to perform this action?

my song manager code that gets all .mp3 files from a folder:

```
public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path

    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/.piano/");
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
}
```

If I be able to pass the address of raw folder to MEDIA_PATH the problem will solve.

Comment: what does "string address" mean?

Comment: @blackbelt I want to pass the raw folder address as a string to MEDIA_PATH.

Comment: The raw folder is wrapped up inside the apk and can only be read from via a call to getResources(). It is not part of the file system so cannot be used in the manner you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.song);
```